# Objective-c enumerateUsingBlock Issue

Tags: objective-c, prefix, enumerate

I want to extract all objects that has prefix "be", but I get only the first object, not all from various indexes. "array" contains various objects, and it contains objects like "be", "become", "beta", "be", "beaver", etc. What is wrong here?

When I use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, it shows only two "be" which is correct in terms of "`isEqualToString:`" and "array" contains actually two "be" from different indexes.

The codes are as follow:

```
NSString *string =@"be";

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 24);

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange: range];

[array enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet options: NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)

{
    //if([obj localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:string] == NSOrderedSame)
    if([obj hasPrefix:string])

    {
        NSLog(@"Object Found: %@ at index: %i",obj, index);

        *stop=YES;

    }

} ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get the first because you stop the loop as soon as you find a single result via the `*stop = YES` line. Remove that.

You should also use `-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` with your test, then take the returned index set and pass it to `-objectsAtIndexes:`.

Comment: Ah, you are right! Sorry for my silly question. By the way, could you give an example on `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`?